# Access object property in a list in velocity template

Tags: java, xml, list, templates, velocity

I want to access an object property in velocity

I have the following.

```
public class myObject(){
    @key("name")
    private String name;

    @key("other")
    private String other;

    /*
      getters and setters here
    */
}
```

Then i have another class which contains a list of myObject objects

```
public class testClass(){
    @key("objectList")
    private List<myObject> randomlist;
}
```

How can i access `name` and `other` of myObject list ?
My velocity looks as follow but doesn't work

```
#macro( getListContent $tag $tag2 $listName)
#foreach($object in [0..$listName-size])
<$tag1>$object-name</$tag1>
<$tag2>$object-other</$tag2>
#end
#end
```

and finally i have

```
#getListContent("name" "other" $testClass.get("objectList"))
```

but this doesn't work. How can i access object properties that are mapped with an annotation `@key` Some help would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [macro](http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch07.html) documentation, In your foreach statement you need to put the list object,

Also name and other are private so they are unreachable,

But you can use `public` getters methods:

```
#macro( getListContent $tag $tag2 $listName)
#foreach($object in $listName)
<$tag1>$object.getName()</$tag1>
<$tag2>$object.getOther()</$tag2>
#end
#end
```